# Making extension for Idle to change its right click menu

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I need to make an extension for Idle, that lets me change its right click menu (context menu?) to add events/options that i want to be there. Mainly for Idle Editor.
I only found documentation on how to change the classic top menu, but havent seen anything about changing the right click menu.

I have a standalone program that lets me make new rmenu in Tkinter and need to implement it into Idle. I found editor.py, where is the rmenu configured, but havent made much out of it.

Comment: I have never made IDLE extensions before but can you bind to right clicking the text area? If so, you might be able to override IDLE's binding with your own.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As discovered, IDLE provides a mechanism for user extensions to declare new main menu entries that IDLE will insert into the main menu.  It does not currently provide a similar mechanism for inserting into the right-click context menu.  This seems like a sensible idea so I added draft issue "IDLE config extension: allow addition to context menu" to the [IDLE project page](https://github.com/orgs/python/projects/31/views/1) with a reference to this question.  I will consider this should I focus on extensions some time in the future.

In the meanwhile, look at the sample extension idlelib/zzdummy.py.  Instead of the menudefs declaration, you would have to add code in `YourExtClass.__init__` to do 1 of 2 things:

1. Add (append) a tuple to `text.rmenu_defs` (a list). The example in `editor.EditorWindow.rmenu_specs` (currently line 589) is `("Close", "<<close-window>>", None)`.  The actual editor `rmenu_specs` is in `pyshell` line 153.  Use `None` for the 3rd member.
2. add a command to `text.rmenu` using code like that in `editor.EditorWindow.make_rmenu`.

The choice depends on whether IDLE installs extensions before or after making rmenu.